# Set document.domain for dojo/request/iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo

Is there a way to set document.domain for dojo/request/iframe?

If I understand it correctly, dojo/request/iframe works by creating an iframe from which the request will be sent... If that's the case, I should be able to somehow set document.domain to that iframe, right?

Comment: What do you mean by setting `document.domain`? If you want to make `GET` and `POST` requests, just use the built-in `get()` and `post()` functions.

Comment: Like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332115/dynamicly-set-document-domain-to-iframe) question, but for dojo/request/iframe.